# How to change register of / after exe "norm /regex" in function

Tags: vim

I have the following custom command and function:

```
function! TestFunc()
    execute "normal /http\<CR>"
endfunction

command! Test2 normal /http<CR>
```

Calling `:Test2` changes register `/` but calling `:call TestFunc()` doesn't change register `/`.

Why is this so? Should I use a custom command in order to change register of /?

Comment: Searching changes the / register but you can manipulate it directly. Do you want to search or change the / register?

Comment: I need to change the register `/`. But the search inside `TestFunc` function does not change it as seen here: http://i.imgur.com/e6bT1qf.png

Comment: Not related, but nonetheless: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search pattern will be restored afterwards; you cannot manipulate it inside a function. (This makes sense for most purposes, unfortunately not for yours.) See `:help function-search-undo`. You can instead manipulate the search pattern (also via `:let @/ = 'pattern'`) directly in the mapping / command that invokes your function.